# Reuse Joined tables in sql

Tags: sql, join, reusability

In my project, I want to reuse from joined tables. Consider the following example:

### **Fields of Main table**

- RowNumber
- CityCode_hometown_customer
- CityCode_hometown_dealer
- CityCode_hometown_seller
- CityCode_birthtown_customer
- CityCode_birthtown_dealer
- CityCode_birthtown_seller

### **And the second table fields**

- CityCode
- CityName

that is the question... if I have to use join for 6 times! Or do you recommend another solution.
see structure from : http://s5.picofile.com/file/8158956276/8.jpg

Comment: I don't think your question is clear enough. What are you trying to achieve with these two tables ?

Comment: If you want the corresponding value for each of those six columns then yes, you'd have to use six joins. Might be worth considering whether your table structure is the best way to handle whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you looking to reuse the JOIN logic across those tables? If so, you may be looking to use a SQL VIEW: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp

Comment: Adding to @AlwaysLearning comment. Are you using the same join within one query?  Most more detail of your query to clarify.

Comment: Unpivot; join; pivot back. Or redesign as per @AnthonyGrist to avoid the unpivot bit.